# Ivory Search error

Tags: search, search-engines

When I open the search engine within the WordPress site, it shows There has been a critical error on this website.[image: There has been a critical error on this website.] I am using Ivory Search plugin doesn't help when deactivating it.

Comment: If the error shows up whether Ivory Search is activated or not, then it's probably not a problem with Ivory. Try turning off your plugins one at a time to see if one of them is the culprit; if not, try switching to a default theme. Also, look into [debugging WordPress](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), which will hopefully give you an idea what's going wrong.